# Have lost the ability to use vi, apt-get, etc. as user ROOT after editing ROOT .bashrc

Tags: linux, debian, privileges, vi

I am using Debian Linux. After logging in today, there was a message saying Firefox had an update. I clicked on it, but it errored out saying 'ldconfig' not found and that usually, /sbin, /usr/local/sbin, etc. are in ROOT's path. I su'd to ROOT, saw there was no 'PATH' variable so added a line to .bashrc as follows:

export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:."

After doing

. .bashrc

I realized I now have no ability to use commands as user ROOT, such as vi, apt-get, more, etc. I 'think' this would have been fine if I put:

PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:.

export PATH

Is that right?

but that's water under the bridge as I am dead in the water as user ROOT now. How can I get out of this problem of not being able to use vi as ROOT and get .bashrc back to the way it was?

TIA, Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've blown up your path. If it's not in your local .bashrc it means it's usually coming from /etc./skel/.bashrc or /etc/bash.bashrc

You should be able to open vim or nano by using explicit paths.

/bin/nano or /bin/vi I think should get you being able to edit the file. It could be /usr/bin/ instead of just /bin/, I'm not as familiar with Debian as I am with Arch and RHEL/SLES

Comment: This fixed things!  /usr/bin/vi enabled me to edit the ROOT .bashrc and get it back to its original form.  thx Insanemal.

Comment: No worries. Not sure why my right answer is downvoted.. But have fun!

Comment: My apologies!  I certainly didn't mean to downvote your answer because you saved me from a mess! I'm new to this site.  I hit the up arrow which I hope was the right thing to do this time :>. Best regards.